# Insert into partition table postgresql

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, database-partitioning

everyone!
I'm trying to insert data from non-partition  table t1 to a partition one t2 with

```
insert into t2 (select * from t1);
```

But I get an error: Partition key of the falling row contains (*column_name*) = (*value*)

What can be wrong?
t2 is partitioned by months by column *date_name* , not *column_name*

P.s. when I try to insert data from partition to partition table with the same way, I get the same error

Hoe should I insert data in partition table?
Version: **Postgresql 11**

Comment: Note that the parentheses around the SELECT are totally useless

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There must be at least one row in `t1` for which there is no matching partition in `t2`. You have to create all partitions for the table *before* you insert data.

To figure out which row gives you trouble, look at the value from the error message.

Comment: As Laurenz Albe say, the problem was in data, which I try to insert

Comment: And also I created partitions from the considerations that the ends of the segment inclusive, that's not a true